# How to define a function without giving explicit formula

Tags: function-construction

I want to have a function and I need to do some complex calculations to obtain an equation and then I want to assign the values to the function and then solve this equation to obtain the unknown function. Is there any way that I can define a function without assigning an explicit formula in order to assign it later?

I mean is there any command like the symbolic function in MATLAB?

Comment: If you just write `f[t]` and `f[t]` was not defined anywhere, Mathematica will leave it as `f[t]` and not replace it by any definition. So you can just use `f[t]` like this for your function.  Mathematica is by default symbolic, You do not need to use syms like with Matlab.

Comment: It would be helpful to have an example with inputs and a clear description of the desired result.